# Jquery 3.5 is not working on IE 11 it is working on IE7?

Tags: jquery

We have upgrade jQuery in our product from 1.2.6 to 3.5.1 . In our product in index.jsp code was written to load document mode IE 7 [response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE7");].
Now we have change that code from IE-7 to IE-11 but now we are getting button view issue [buttons are looking small] .

**The functionality working perfectly on other browser except IE .**

Please suggest what we need to do .

Comment: Please see [ask] - please include the smallest amount of code that demonstrates the problem - the code that works in one browser but the another, include the setHeader if relevant and exactly which browser you mean by "IE" (there's multiple, try include a version number if you can).  See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of jQuery [only supports Internet Explorer 9+](https://jquery.com/browser-support/), so you’d have to downgrade to an earlier version of jQuery.

(If your users are using Windows XP then you might have to suggest they try a different browser.)

Comment: Thanks Thomas for reply . But we don't want to downgrade now . Instead of downgrading if we keep jQuery 3.5.1 we are facing button issue which are not displaying properly . That are looking very small and ui view distorted. **Could you please suggest what we need to do to fix that ?**

Comment: @Nachiketkumar if you want to support IE11 and the latest jQuery supports IE9+, why do you need to downgrade?

Comment: Hi Daniel , We don't want to downgrade . After upgrade we are facing issue . Button are looking small in size and UI distortion . Can you please suggest how we can fix that?

Comment: @Nachiketkumar as others had said, in your question you need to be able to reproduce the issue in order to get help in Stackoverflow. In other words, to provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This question is about to be closed.